# Core Data - how to handle _persistentStoreCoordinator errors on first release?

Tags: ios, core-data, error-handling

I'm just putting the finishing touches to my app for its first release.  I've successfully implemented Core Data but not sure what to do about the `persistentStoreCoordinator` method that says "Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately."

If I change the model for an update I will look into migration but for now what should I do here?

```
// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*

         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
         @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Core Data "Production" Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262704/iphone-core-data-production-error-handling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure of a `NSPersistentStore` being added to a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is a **developer level error**.  This should never fail in production if you have done adequate testing.  Therefore I always put my own version of the following:

```
NSLog(@"Failed to load persistent store: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
abort(); //My personal version throws a NSException
```

This is a hard error and should be a hard error 99% of the time.  This absolutely should crash in development so that you can know if it happens and you are forced to solve it. Since it is a developer level error you can leave this code in place since it should never happen in production and if it does, you want a crash report sent to Apple.

Comment: It could fail in production if the database becomes corrupt or a migration fails after an app update. If you abort then the user would need to uninstall the app and reinstall it again but it might not be obvious to them that is the reason for the crash. You would be better showing an alert and perhaps allowing the option to delete the database file so it can be recreated without requiring to re-install the app.

Comment: Migration failure is a developer level event that is caught in testing.  Core Data databases do not just become corrupt.  Other than setting the db aside I do not recommend trying to handle this error in production, let the application crash so you can get a crash log and correct the gap in testing.

Comment: What about when the device is full? It doesn't make so much sense to crash the app in that case, but just inform the user about it.

Comment: Why wouldn't you crash the app?  If you cannot persist data then you are going to leave the user in a bad state.  In addition, iOS and macOS don't let the disk get full.  The OS will delete caches and other files to keep a full disk from happening.  In Unix, a 100% full disk generally turns into a bricked device so is avoided by the OS at nearly any cost.

Comment: @Marcus S. Zarra you are right and I'm tired today :) indeed we are talking about when the persistent store coordinator is first instantiated here. I was thinking, wrongly, about the case the user would try to dump something on his device to make room without quitting the app, but it doesn't make sense at all cause the persistent store had already failed. Even though the device wouldn't be bricked and still semi-responsive, for the user it would be better to have the app start freshly. This is one of those edge cases where I could be mislead

Comment: Hardware issues are always possible and can cause all kinds of data corruption. I have this error on one user out of thousands so I think that rules out a developer error. The only solution is to delete the store and start over, otherwise your app will crash again with every restart.