# How to handle errors in NSPersistentContainer.loadPersistentStores?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My AppDelegate came with the following all familiar Core Data template:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "newsapp")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

It also had the following comment:

> The persistent container for the application. This implementation
>   creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
>   application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
>   error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
>
> Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
>   `fatalError()` causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
>
> Typical reasons for an error here include:
>
> - The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
> - The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
> - The device is out of space.
> - The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
>
> Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.

True, calling it quits in this place is a bad idea not only it is not allowed in production apps, but because, [as I read elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323611/core-data-how-to-handle-persistentstorecoordinator-errors-on-first-release#comment58274541_21323705), if a data store gets corrupted for any reason, a user would have to reinstall the app not knowing about that. A user can delete and forget my app just as well in this case.

Now, how one is supposed to handle such and other errors here? Even if I write the error handling code, how do I test that is works correctly if these errors almost never happen?

I looked all over, but couldn't find any example.

Comment: I think you should create an alert message to it and that's it.

Comment: @Mannopson alert message and then what? try again? crash the app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In most cases `fatalError` is the only "handling" that makes sense for this error, though you might want to display an alert telling the user what's happening first. If you need your persistent store but you can't load it, you're kind of screwed.

Some of those errors are things that should come up during development. Like store migration or data protection problems-- you need to be testing that, and if necessary fixing the app before release. For cases like that, `fatalError` actually makes sense because only you will ever experience it.

Of those listed examples, the only one that might come up unexpectedly that can be awkward to test is the device being out of space. You *could* check available space and alert the user. But you still don't have any way to recover from the error unless your app is using a lot of space that you can clear out. If this happens, iOS will already be warning them that they're running out of space, so doing it yourself isn't necessary.

If you don't have a lot of data you can clear out, `fatalError` still makes sense here.

Comment: My problem when device is out of space. I should keep using the `fatalError` for this case?

Comment: Maybe. As with any error handling situation, you need to answer the question, what can your app possibly do to recover? Is there any way your app can be useful if the device is full? If so, try to do that. If not, then there's no other way to respond.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So I have not any recovery options yet. This error throws only the first time right? ( When an app is first time launched ). It would be better if I can check the status of `persistentContainer`. If it's successfully created the user must be able to add a data to the `persistentStore`. Is it possible to check this status? Thanks again

Comment: @Mannopson this checking is done every time the Persistent Container gets initialized for the first time (it's a lazy var), thus it depends on the way you have designed your app in regards to the CoreData Stack. If you are sticking to the way it is setup by XCode template, and you first access the Core Data Stack in your App delegate (by doing for example a fetch or when injecting its viewContext in the main View Controller from there) that's when you'll get this error in case the device is full. Anyway as Tom Harrington has explained, the system will already do its job of informing the user

Comment: Do never use fatalError in production code. This makes your application crash if encountered.