# Why is NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification called twice with the deleted objects after a rollback?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, rollback

I have a problem with `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` where after inserting an object and then performing a rollback (so it is deleted), the change notification about the deletion is called twice. This unexpected notification causes complications down the line for me that I have traced back to this issue. I've edited [Apple's Earthquakes example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Earthquakes/Introduction/Intro.html) to demonstrate this problem. Edits are:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self reloadTableView:self];
    
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(contextObjectsDidChangeNotification:)
     name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
     object:self.managedObjectContext];
    
    AAPLQuake* quake = (AAPLQuake *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Quake" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    
    NSLog(@"Why is deleted notified twice?");
    [self.managedObjectContext rollback];
}

- (void)contextObjectsDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notify{
    NSLog(@"contextObjectsDidChangeNotification:");
    NSDictionary* userInfo = notify.userInfo;
    NSSet* inserted = userInfo[NSInsertedObjectsKey];
    if(inserted){
        NSLog(@"\tinserted %ld", inserted.count);
    }
    NSSet *deleted = userInfo[NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    if(deleted){
        NSLog(@"\tdeleted %ld", deleted.count);
    }
}
```

Running this results in the following output:

```
2015-12-23 00:15:20.086 Earthquakes[7631:5431685] Why is deleted called twice?
2015-12-23 00:15:20.086 Earthquakes[7631:5431685] contextObjectsDidChangeNotification:
2015-12-23 00:15:20.086 Earthquakes[7631:5431685]   inserted 1
2015-12-23 00:15:20.086 Earthquakes[7631:5431685] contextObjectsDidChangeNotification:
2015-12-23 00:15:20.087 Earthquakes[7631:5431685]   deleted 1
2015-12-23 00:15:20.087 Earthquakes[7631:5431685] contextObjectsDidChangeNotification:
2015-12-23 00:15:20.087 Earthquakes[7631:5431685]   deleted 1
```

Sample project available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/305394/Earthquakes-with-bug.zip).

Does anyone know why this would happen? I'm experiencing it on both OS X 10.11.2 and iOS 9.2.

Comment: Where did you removeObserver ?

Comment: I can confirm that I am seeing the same behaviour, not sure what the cause is though.

Comment: Thanks for confirming you see the same behaviour. I experimented with using an undo manager instead of rollback and it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I see the same behavior and I don't know why it's happening. However, it appears that you can distinguish the first call from the second by looking at the `hasChanges` property of the managed object. On the first call, `hasChanges` is YES, and on the second call it's NO. That should, at least, be enough to avoid processing the delete yourself twice.

The same change happens on the object's `deleted` property, so it might be best to check both.

Answer (score 1):

`rollback` makes a call to `processPendingChanges` and the first notification is a result of the object being deleted, and seems to have all the other values as expected (`inserted` and `deleted` are both true).

The second notification is a result of `processPendingChanges` being called a second time in the implementation of `rollback`.  Note that it's not even marked as `deleted` this time around.

At first, I thought it may be due to deletion propagation, but the second notification happens even if `propagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent` is set to NO.

The following trace is just of the `rollback` method (I removed all method calls except those on `NSManagedObjectContext` to keep it short - I also removed calls to retain/release).

There is probably a good reason to make the second call to `processPendingChanges` because a fair amount of work happens there (see the end of this post).

If I had to make a guess, I would say that there is a bug in the implementation of rollback, where deleted objects are not being removed from the data for the second notification.

I recommend two courses of action.  First, file a bug report with apple.  Second, when you process object change events, check the `deleted` attribute of objects in the deleted set of the notification, and ignore any that are not marked as `deleted`.

Here is the trace...

```
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext rollback
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext discardEditing
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext isEditing
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext propagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext setPropagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentChanges:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _postRefreshedObjectsNotificationAndClearList
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _processReferenceQueue:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _registerClearStateWithUndoManager
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _establishEventSnapshotsForObject:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _enqueueEndOfEventNotification
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentChanges:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _registerClearStateWithUndoManager
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _updateUnprocessedOwnDestinations:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _propagatePendingDeletesAtEndOfEvent:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _processPendingDeletions:withInsertions:withUpdates:withNewlyForgottenList:withRemovedChangedObjects:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _processPendingInsertions:withDeletions:withUpdates:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _processPendingUpdates:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _registerUndoForModifiedObjects:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _registerUndoForInsertedObjects:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _registerUndoForDeletedObjects:withDeletedChanges:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _registerUndoForOperation:withObjects:withExtraArguments:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _updateUndoTransactionForThisEvent:withDeletions:withUpdates:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearRefreshedObjects
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentlyForgottenObjects:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _forgetObject:propagateToObjectStore:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _forgetObject:propagateToObjectStore:removeFromRegistry:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _processReferenceQueue:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _isDeallocating
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _forgetObject:propagateToObjectStore:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _forgetObject:propagateToObjectStore:removeFromRegistry:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _resetAllChanges
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearUnprocessedUpdates
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearUpdates
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearUnprocessedInsertions
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearInsertions
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearUnprocessedDeletions
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearDeletions
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearLockedObjects
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _clearRefreshedObjects
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext _incrementUndoTransactionID
- NSManagedObjectContext NSObject willChangeValueForKey:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSObject observationInfo
- NSManagedObjectContext NSObject _implicitObservationInfo
- NSManagedObjectContext NSObject didChangeValueForKey:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSObject _pendingChangeNotificationsArrayForKey:create:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext setPropagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent:
- NSManagedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:
```