# Why doesn't Core Data just save all that works and ignore the empty entity?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Given the following console output, why is my Core Data save failing? 
It seems that the `biz` entity is empty. I have 20 "`biz`" entities, and only 1 is most likely empty. Why does the whole save fail?

Why doesn't Core Data just save all that works and ignore the empty entity? Instead, it returns `Error in saving Error in Saving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570`.

**Here's my console log:**

```
2011-11-08 11:37:49.059 BadgerNew[3808:4503] <0x38a520 GrabClass.m:(509)> Biz to save <Business: 0x32e2550> (entity: Business; id: 0x32b7dd0 <x-coredata:///Business/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255489> ; data: {
    Bookmark = 0;
    Building = nil;
    City = "0x32f06e0 <x-coredata:///City/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255396>";
    Distance = "484.0799568283629";
    Districts =     (
        "0x326b7a0 <x-coredata:///District/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255398>"
    );
    Email = nil;
    ID = 22302;
    Images =     (
        "0x32df100 <x-coredata:///Image/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255494>"
    );
    InBuildingAddress = "Blok De Unit 1-2";
    LatitudeLongitude = "0x32755f0 <x-coredata:///LatitudeLongitude/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255495>";
    Like = 0;
    OpeningHour = nil;
    Phones =     (
        "0x32def60 <x-coredata:///Phone/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255493>",
        "0x32e2d60 <x-coredata:///Phone/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255490>",
        "0x32dea90 <x-coredata:///Phone/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255491>",
        "0x32decb0 <x-coredata:///Phone/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255492>"
    );
    Price = 0;
    Promotions =     (
    );
    Rating = "0x3275000 <x-coredata:///Rating/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255496>";
    Reviews =     (
    );
    Street = "Jl. Panjang Kedoya No. 1";
    Tags =     (
    );
    TimeStamp = nil;
    Title = "Bank BNI Graha Elok Mas";
    URLs =     (
    );
    Website = nil;
    Zip = 11520;
    pinAndLineNumber = 0;
})
2011-11-08 11:37:49.095 BadgerNew[3808:4503] <0x427c0 TreadClass.m:(82)> Error in Saving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)" UserInfo=0x31fbd0 {NSValidationErrorObject=<Business: 0x328c660> (entity: Business; id: 0x332840 <x-coredata:///Business/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255441> ; data: {
    Bookmark = 0;
    Building = nil;
    City = nil;
    Distance = "-1";
    Districts =     (
    );
    Email = nil;
    ID = "";
    Images =     (
    );
    InBuildingAddress = nil;
    LatitudeLongitude = nil;
    Like = 0;
    OpeningHour = nil;
    Phones =     (
    );
    Price = 0;
    Promotions =     (
    );
    Rating = nil;
    Reviews =     (
    );
    Street = nil;
    Tags =     (
    );
    TimeStamp = nil;
    Title = nil;
    URLs =     (
    );
    Website = nil;
    Zip = nil;
    pinAndLineNumber = 0;
}), NSValidationErrorKey=Title, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}
2011-11-08 11:37:51.307 BadgerNew[3808:1403] <0x427c0 TreadClass.m:(82)> Error in Saving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)" UserInfo=0x322ca30 {NSValidationErrorObject=<Business: 0x323f510> (entity: Business; id: 0x323f6a0 <x-coredata:///Business/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF25511> ; data: {
    Bookmark = 0;
    Building = nil;
    City = nil;
    Distance = "-1";
    Districts =     (
    );
    Email = nil;
    ID = "";
    Images =     (
    );
    InBuildingAddress = nil;
    LatitudeLongitude = nil;
    Like = 0;
    OpeningHour = nil;
    Phones =     (
    );
    Price = 0;
    Promotions =     (
    );
    Rating = nil;
    Reviews =     (
    );
    Street = nil;
    Tags =     (
    );
    TimeStamp = nil;
    Title = nil;
    URLs =     (
    );
    Website = nil;
    Zip = nil;
    pinAndLineNumber = 0;
}), NSValidationErrorKey=Title, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}
2011-11-08 11:37:53.284 BadgerNew[3808:1b03] <0x427c0 TreadClass.m:(82)> Error in Saving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)" UserInfo=0x3a4c90 {NSValidationErrorObject=<Business: 0x32aee0> (entity: Business; id: 0x300480 <x-coredata:///Business/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255220> ; data: {
    Bookmark = 0;
    Building = nil;
    City = nil;
    Distance = "-1";
    Districts =     (
    );
    Email = nil;
    ID = "";
    Images =     (
    );
    InBuildingAddress = nil;
    LatitudeLongitude = nil;
    Like = 0;
    OpeningHour = nil;
    Phones =     (
    );
    Price = 0;
    Promotions =     (
    );
    Rating = nil;
    Reviews =     (
    );
    Street = nil;
    Tags =     (
    );
    TimeStamp = nil;
    Title = nil;
    URLs =     (
    );
    Website = nil;
    Zip = nil;
    pinAndLineNumber = 0;
}), NSValidationErrorKey=Title, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}
2011-11-08 11:37:56.480 BadgerNew[3808:4403] <0x427c0 TreadClass.m:(82)> Error in Saving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)" UserInfo=0x3c5e10 {NSValidationErrorObject=<Business: 0x32d4530> (entity: Business; id: 0x3d0240 <x-coredata:///Business/t069264E3-D89C-4D4A-92D9-8A190B7CF255296> ; data: {
    Bookmark = 0;
    Building = nil;
    City = nil;
    Distance = "-1";
    Districts =     (
    );
    Email = nil;
    ID = "";
    Images =     (
    );
    InBuildingAddress = nil;
    LatitudeLongitude = nil;
    Like = 0;
    OpeningHour = nil;
    Phones =     (
    );
    Price = 0;
    Promotions =     (
    );
    Rating = nil;
    Reviews =     (
    );
    Street = nil;
    Tags =     (
    );
    TimeStamp = nil;
    Title = nil;
    URLs =     (
    );
    Website = nil;
    Zip = nil;
    pinAndLineNumber = 0;
}), NSValidationErrorKey=Title, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone Core Data Unresolved error while saving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283960/iphone-core-data-unresolved-error-while-saving)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283960/iphone-core-data-unresolved-error-while-saving) explains it best. To quote from the accepted answer:

> It means there's a mandatory property has been assigned nil. Either in
>   your *.xcodatamodel check the "optional" box or when you are saving to
>   the managedObjectContext make sure that your properties are filled in.

Comment: I know. But if I want to save 100 bizs and one of them doesn't validate, why the rest don't get saved?

Comment: Because it doesn't. I totally agree that it should - but that just isn't how it works. If you want it to work like that then you should file a bug report, or make that property optional and implement a custom will save method that does what you need.

Comment: No. I just want to make sure that it's the way it is :). It's surprising. Where does it says that it works that way? Of course I can save one by one.