# Need clarification on Cocoa error code 1570

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

With help from the great posts here, I understand the error. But I need some clarification please.

Say my managed object context (schema) has 3 tables (entities), and say each entity had 3 attributes of which one attribute for each entry is NOT optional.

So now for the first time, my app creates a managed object for the first entity, filling its mandatory attribute; app has not created managed objects for the second and third entities yet - didn't have to yet. When I try to save the context at this point, I get error code 1570. Is it because I have not filled out values for the second and 3rd entities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps you.

But The cocoa error 1570 means that mandatory fields are not filled in. So please make sure your mandatory fields are not nil.

Comment: I know that now. But I did fill in mandatory field for the managed object in the first entity. I don't have managed object for 2nd and 3rd entities yet.

Answer (score 0):

[iphone Core Data Unresolved error while saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283960/iphone-core-data-unresolved-error-while-saving)

Yep it was a mandatory field that was not filled in. The post above showed me which field.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously run it on your device (or simulator) with the attribute set as mandatory and then changed it to optional, delete the app from the device before running again. That was the problem for my app.

Hope that helps someone! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was setting a mandatory `BOOL` property directly as `YES` or `NO`, but you should use

> NSNumber numberWithBOOL

in order to make it work.